# WPF windows switching

Tags: wpf

My wpf app have two windows. One is used for playing musics, one for doing some other things. 
I switch from windows 1 to windows 2 using code below:

```
Window2 window2 = new Window2 ();
App.Current.MainWindow = window2 ;
window2 .Show();
this.Close();
```

The problem is window2 is showed but window1 is still running(music still playing) althought window1 was disappeared (I hear the musics's sound)

How can i stop all window1's  business before swtiching to window2?

Comment: `window2.Show()` do not returns until the window is closed, so `this.Close()` is not called when you think it is.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I have edited my question for more clear. Have you got any idea in this case?

Comment: The obvious stop windows1 businesses.  If there are many businesses and you want them to stop themselves then can use a stop event and have the business register event handlers to stop themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Window1_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Pause/stop music
}

private void Window1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Resume music
}
```